# filter en ng-repeat when datas are defered bu rootscop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

First, sorry if my english isn't very good.

I am developing a mobile application and I have a problem for filtering ng-repeat.
The data are loaded from a online json file (then stored locally after) in the $rootScope and filter applied does not work.

a part of my app.js

```
   app.run(function($rootScope, $http, $location, dataService) {
            $rootScope.globalDatas = false;
            if($rootScope.globalDatas === false) {
                dataService.getGlobalDatas(reload).then(function(dataset){
                    $rootScope.globalDatas = dataset;
                }, function(error){
                    alert(error);
                });
            }
    });
```

dataService.js

```
    app.service('dataService', ['$q', '$http', 'saveFile',function($q, $http, saveFile) {
    var that = this;
    this.globalData = false;

        this.getGlobalDatas = function(reload) {
            var defered = $q.defer();
            if(reload)
                that.globalData = false;

            if (that.globalData !== false) { 
                defered.resolve(that.globalData);
            } else {
                var url = "My json url"
                $http.get(url).success(function(dataset, status) {
                    that.globalData = dataset; 
                    defered.resolve(dataset);
                }).error(function(data, status) { 
                    defered.reject("Erreur, le fichier de données n'a pas été trouvé, merci de mettre à jour l'application via la menu.");
                });
            }
            return defered.promise;
        };
    }]);
```

My home.html . datas are display in this view

```
<section class="page">
    <div id="recherche">
        <input type="text" ng-model="recherche" placeholder="Recherche" class="clasicInput">
        {{recherche | json}}
    </div>
    <!--  | orderBy:'firstdate' -->
    <article class="elementListe" ng-repeat="element in datas | filter: {titre: recherche}" ng-click="goUrl(element.id)">
        <div class="affiche">
            <img src="{{getURl(element.affiche, 'evenement/'+element.id+'/affiche/')}}" alt="{{element.titre}}">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenue">
            <h1 ng-bind-html="element.titre | characters: nombreCaractere"></h1>
            <div class="date">
                <span ng-if="element.dates.length > 1">du {{getDate(element.firstdate)}} au {{getDate(element.dates[1].dateevent)}}</span>
                <span ng-if="element.dates.length == 1">le {{getDate(element.firstdate)}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="lieu">
                {{globalDatas.lieu[element.id_lieu].titre}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fleche">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

the filter on the title does not work. does anyone know why?

Comment: Could it be because you write `titre` instead of `title` ?

Comment: Thx, but titre is correct (it's french app and the json is in french).
The ng-repeat is display correctly but the aren't filtered.

Comment: I have test | orderBy:'firstdate' or | orderBy:'-firstdate' in my ng-repeat but it's dont work to. is it possible it's because my data are defered?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Could you prepare a fiddle demonstrating the problem ?

Comment: I have publish the app on a web (there small display bug): http://s315332719.onlinehome.fr/testapp/#/home

The serache input on the top don't filter the ng-repeat..

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/4qVvQ/ If you want help you need to prepare a fiddle (not a live site)

Comment: I have creat fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/58y7u/19/

I just found the problem, my data is not in a table but in an object. Thank you very much, I will modify the data structure.

Comment: At least 50% of the time, creating a fiddle to demonstrate the problem is enought to find what's wrong ;)